# Queue upload for internet connection

Tags: node.js

I am working to create a web app that can be used both online and offline.  Currently, I'm stuck on the issue of how to queue the data and visually update with JS so that it can be ready to upload to the server when it gets back online.

I really wish I had some ideas but I don't, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I understand you want to upload from a web client to a node.js server. If your question is about the behavior of the client when the server is unreachable, that doesn't seem like a node.js question to me. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I'm used to the CRUD enviroment where you perform basic http requests.  However, if the client is offline when they are using the app(pinned to homescreen), how do I store the data-they 'send'-to a queue that will update the server once a connection is acquired.  My worry is a direct request to the server will make the app unusable with errors if it is offline.  Did that help?  I'm assuming this 'queue' would occur in javascript in JSON or an array...